# Ajustar janela do Tkinter e widjets de acordo com resolução da tela

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

Olá, estou desenvolvendo uma GUI em python com TKinter. Estou tentando fazer com que o setup de widgets que montei se adeque a resolução do monitor.

apliquei o seguinte codigo.

```
    janela = tk.Tk()

    lado, cima = (janela.winfo_screenwidth()), (janela.winfo_screenheight())

    janela.geometry('%dx%d+0+0' % (lado,cima))
```

Porém isso só me garante que a janela abrirá na resolução do monitor porém não ajusta as dimensões dos pixels dos widgets com a janela.

é possível tal ajuste com TKinter?

Comment: Tkinter nao é muito poderoso mas você vai ter que usar o gerenciador de layout pack, pesquisa sobre o pack que você vai entender melhor.

Comment: Patrick Machado, bom dia! Eu comprei alguns cursos de Kivy e, pelo que tenho visto, é possível ajustar os widgets redimensionando-os por porcentagem. No Tkinter tenho a mesma dúvida que você.

Comment: pack, grid e place, este ultimo permite posicionamento relativo da da widget, é possivel fazer uma ui ajustavel a qualquer munitor, só que não tem função que gerencie isso, isso significa que vc mesmo tera que escrever essa função

Comment: olha não sei se nesse tempo a atualização aceitava fazer esse ajuste responsivo.. mas a versão que utilizo me permite manipular a janela assim como no html ou css para sites.

Answer (score -1):

Olá, desculpe não responder logo, estava muito ocupado.
Mas é o seguinte, não tem código nenhum que eu conheça que deixe os *widgets*, *frames* ou/e *label's* como uma dimensão na qual se ajuste ao monitor. Porque pense comigo, se você passa um parâmentro pro IDLE para que ajuste a tela principal ao monitor está ok, mas ai você deverá definir um tamanho para os objetos colocados dentro da tela que irá imprimir, como, *widgets*, *frames* e *label's*. Então a melhor saída no momento seria organizar seus objetos com gerenciador de layout *Pack* ou *Grid*, poderia ser em *Linha* e *Coluna*, se você não definir tamanho ou não definir o lugar onde ele deve ficar, vai dar erro, mas a sua saída está aqui:

Monte sua estrutura de códigos, coloque botões, label e etc., mas no final você empacota tudo e centraliza. Assim quando outro usuário ou você mesmo for abrir o programa em outro computador com outra resolução de monitor, sempre os botões, widgets e label's estarão no centro.

Bom eu espero ter mesmo ajudado, e desculpe mais uma vez por não responder logo.